# How to save Detectron2 model as a vanilla pytorch model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, detectron

I have a `Faster-RCNN` model trained with `Detectron2`. [Model weights are saved as `model.pth`](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1S5LhdZiKS8dXqUeXYfDEOVkfBxVMuZsk).

I have [my pickled `config.yml` file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QVANZKjzQdNGQuk7lVKzzbj5RnJyQTnL/view?usp=sharing) and there are a couple of ways to load this model:

```
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
from detectron2.checkpoint import DetectionCheckpointer

cfg = get_cfg()
config_name = "config.yml" 
cfg.merge_from_file(config_name)

cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = './model.pth'
model = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

OR

model_ = build_model(cfg) 
model = DetectionCheckpointer(model_).load("./model.pth")
```

Also, you can get predictions from this model individually as [given in official documentation](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/models.html#model-input-format):

```
image = np.array(Image.open('page4.jpg'))[:,:,::-1] # RGB to BGR format
tensor_image = torch.from_numpy(image.copy()).permute(2, 0, 1) # B, channels, W, H


with torch.no_grad():
    output = torch_model([{"image":tensor_image}])
```

running the following commands:

```
print(type(model))
print(type(model.model))
print(type(model.model.backbone))
```

Gives you:

```
<class 'detectron2.engine.defaults.DefaultPredictor'>
<class 'detectron2.modeling.meta_arch.rcnn.GeneralizedRCNN'>
<class 'detectron2.modeling.backbone.fpn.FPN'>
```

**Problem: I want to use [GradCam for model explainability](https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam) and it uses `pytorch` models as [given in this tutorial](https://analyticsindiamag.com/explainable-image-classification-using-faster-r-cnn-and-grad-cam/)**

How can I turn `detectron2` model in vanilla `pytorch` model?

I have tried:

```
torch.save(model.model.state_dict(), "torch_weights.pth")
torch.save(model.model, "torch_model.pth")


from torchvision.models.detection import fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn

dummy = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False, num_classes=1)
# dummy.load_state_dict(torch.load('./model.pth', map_location = 'cpu')) 
dummy.load_state_dict(torch.load('./torch_weights.pth', map_location = 'cpu'))
```

but obviously, I'm getting errors due to the different layer names and sizes etc.

I've also tried:

```
class TorchModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model.model
    
    def forward(self, image):
        return self.model([{"image":image}])[0]['instances']
```

But it doesn't work with `.backbone`, `.layers` etc

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the notebook [here](https://jacobgil.github.io/pytorch-gradcam-book/Class%20Activation%20Maps%20for%20Object%20Detection%20With%20Faster%20RCNN.html) focuses exactly on using GradCam for Faster-RCNN models, so the summary [here](https://jacobgil.github.io/pytorch-gradcam-book/Class%20Activation%20Maps%20for%20Object%20Detection%20With%20Faster%20RCNN.html#this-is-too-long-just-show-me-some-code) should basically work for you. (Note that I have made some minor changes to this example to fit your variable names and add labels and bounding boxes.)

```
import cv2
from pytorch_grad_cam import AblationCAM, EigenCAM
from pytorch_grad_cam.ablation_layer import AblationLayerFasterRCNN
from pytorch_grad_cam.utils.model_targets import FasterRCNNBoxScoreTarget
from pytorch_grad_cam.utils.reshape_transforms import fasterrcnn_reshape_transform
from pytorch_grad_cam.utils.image import show_cam_on_image, scale_accross_batch_and_channels, scale_cam_image

# I have modified the code there slightly
im = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
outputs = model(im)
labels, boxes = outputs["instances"].pred_classes, outputs["instances"].pred_boxes

targets = [FasterRCNNBoxScoreTarget(labels=labels, bounding_boxes=boxes)]
target_layers = [model.model.backbone]
cam = AblationCAM(model.model,
                  target_layers, 
                  use_cuda=torch.nn.cuda.is_available(), 
                  reshape_transform=fasterrcnn_reshape_transform,
                  ablation_layer=AblationLayerFasterRCNN(),
                  ratio_channels_to_ablate=1.0)

# or a very fast alternative

cam = EigenCAM(model.model,
              target_layers, 
              use_cuda=torch.nn.cuda.is_available(), 
              reshape_transform=fasterrcnn_reshape_transform)
```

Comment: thanks for helping out.  I have updated the drive links for model weights, config. Can you please test it on [this document image](https://akm-img-a-in.tosshub.com/indiatoday/images/bodyeditor/202112/0006_8-1200x3509.jpg?ouC6l.zNAe.10b1dIR_E8QqyD6jmJ5_g) . I got a coupple of erros and in the end `KeyError: 'pool'`